# Cannot multiply variables?

Tags: android, kotlin

So I'm trying to learn Kotlin and i'm a few days in.  I am trying to build a Coin Calculator app that will take input of quantity of each type of coin you have and then using a class value it will add up all your change and tell you a total.  I apologize for not being able to be too specific other than my error: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
public final operator fun times(other: Byte): Double defined in kotlin.Double
public final operator fun times(other: Double): Double defined in kotlin.Double

it's showing these on my quarter total and dime total variables.

As I said I am new and actively studying looking for insight on what I am doing wrong, also any other advice over my messy coding that you see would be greatly appreciated.

-Thanks!

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    //MyCode
    val submitButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.submit)
    var quarterQuan: EditText = findViewById(R.id.quarterInput)
    var dimeQuan: EditText = findViewById(R.id.dimeInput)
    submitButton.setOnClickListener{
        val dime = Dime()
        val quarter= Quarter()
        var quarterTotal: Float = quarter.quarterVal*quarterQuan
        var dimeTotal: Float = dime.dimeVal*dimeQuan
        var cashTotal: Float = dimeTotal + quarterTotal
        val resultTextViewLabel: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textResult)
        resultTextViewLabel.text = cashTotal.toString()

    }
}
```

}

class Quarter(){
val quarterVal = 0.25

}

class Dime(){
val dimeVal = 0.10

}

Answer (score 0):

`quarterQuan` and `dimeQuan` are of type `EditText` (they are not numbers) and cannot be multiplied with a Float.

What you need to do is to read the values of these EditTexts:

```
val quarterEditTextValue = quarterQuan.text.toString().toFloat()
val dimeEditTextValue = dimeQuan.text.toString().toFloat()
```

You can then use these values for multiplication

```
var quarterTotal = quarter.quarterVal*quarterEditTextValue
var dimeTotal = dime.dimeVal*dimeEditTextValue
```

Have to add that you need to make each initial EditText value to be `0.0` to avoid `NumberFormatException`.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/quarterInput"
        android:text="0.0" .... />
```